# Variance when sum is given

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be iid, positive and square integrable random variables. Further let $S:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. I am trying to compute $\mathbb E[X_1^2|S]$. What i got so far is
$$\frac{S^2}n=\frac1n\mathbb E[S^2|S]=\mathbb E[X_1^2|S]+(n-1)\mathbb E[X_1X_2|S]$$

Is there any clever trick to get rid of $\mathbb E[X_1X_2|S]$?

EDIT: A similar version is
$$Var(S|S)=\mathbb E(S^2|S)-(\mathbb E(S|S))^2=0$$
but also
$$0=Var(S |S)=n\,Var(X_1|S)+n\,(n-1)\,Cov(X_1,X_2|S).$$

That implies
$$Var(X_1|S)=-(n-1)\,Cov(X_1,X_2|S)$$

Comment: This may not be easy.  Consider $X_i=0$ or $1$ with probabilities $1-p$ and $p$.  Then $\mathbb E[X_1X_2\mid S=0] =\mathbb E[X_1X_2\mid S=1]=0$ while $\mathbb E[X_1X_2\mid S=2]=1$ and this hints to me that the general calculation is not simple